# How to predict next month given a fitted model?

Tags: r, predict, gam

Say I have fitted a GAM model to the data:

```
model <- gam(Cases~s(Time, k=5, bs="cs"), data=dengue, family = gaussian(link = indentity))
```

The data goes up to 32 weeks. How do I predict say the next 4 weeks (33rd to 36th week)?

```
prediction <- predict(model, se.fit=T, n.ahead=4)
```

Maybe something like this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide `predict()` with a data frame of new data to make the predictions on. See the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.8-34/topics/predict.gam) for details.

In your case this would mean something like:

```
testdata = data.frame(Time= c(33:36))
prediction <- predict(model, newdata = testdata)
```